# How can I pass parameter to modal on the laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3, bootstrap-modal

My view is like this :

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    ...
    <tr>
        @for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
        <td id="image-view-li-{{$i}}" style="display: none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-option">
            <img id="image-view-{{$i}}" src="https://myshop.co.id/img/shop1.jpg" alt="">
        </td>

        @section('modal')
        @include('components.modal.option',['i'=>$i]) 
        @endsection
        @endfor
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

When I click the td, it will call modal

My modal is like this :

```
<div id="modal-option" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="javascript:" id="image-edit-{{$i}}">
                            <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <a href="javascript:" class="text-danger" id="image-delete-{{$i}}">
                            <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pass parameter `$i` to modal

For example, I click td that have $i = 3. Then it will pass paramter $i = 3 to modal

I had try it like my above code

But, $id sent is always 0

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

I had find solution

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
<td id="image-view-li-{{$i}}" style="display: none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-option-{{$i}}">
    <img id="image-view-{{$i}}" src="https://myshop.co.id/img/shop1.jpg" alt="">
</td>
@include('components.modal.option',['i'=>$i]) 
@endfor


<div id="modal-option-{{$i}}" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    ...
</div>
```

It works

Comment: Where's the opening of ```@endif```?

Comment: @aceraven777, Sorry. I had update my question

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are loading the modal with javascript or jquery when you click on td. Now how do you think javascript will pick up a variable which was generated by PHP. You need add an attribute on td which holds the id and add a logic in javascript so that when the td is clicked it will pick the value of the attribute carrying id. I hope you understand the concept

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I had try your concept

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to wrap the modal in modal section? Maybe you want this solution?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    ...
    <tr>
        @for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
        <td id="image-view-li-{{$i}}" style="display: none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-option">
            <img id="image-view-{{$i}}" src="https://myshop.co.id/img/shop1.jpg" alt="">

            @include('components.modal.option',['i'=>$i])
        </td>
        @endfor
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: I updated my answer, put the modal inside ```<td>```